# C# I get System.Object[] instead of the value in array

Tags: c#, arrays

Another question about arrays. When i create an array and fill it from keyboard, the console shows several System.Object[] instead of the value I set. For example, if i create a [5] array i get 36 System.Object[] instead of my 5 values. Why is that? This is a code I´m using:

```
 object[] row = new object[5];

 public void fill()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Set the values" + (i+1));
                row[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

 public void view()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The values are:");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(row);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program objeto = new Program();

        objeto.fill();
        objeto.view();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

There are no error messages, but when on screen i get this afer setting the 5 values:

The values are:

> System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]
>   System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]
>   System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]
>   System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]
>   System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]
>   System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]System.Object[]

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `row` is an array, the default `.ToString()` method is printing the type, which is `System.Object[]`.

Try writing the value of `row[j]` instead the value of `row`.

Except, you seem to have two loops that almost seem like you are wanting to print a multidimensional array, which your array isn't. So the outer `for` loop is unnecessary, unless you are wanting to print 5 rows of the same data.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, i made the changes you mention and now i get on screen the values, but am recieving an IndexOutOfRangeException after the array is shown. T_T

Comment: Since arrays start from zero, your condition in for loop should be j <= 4 or j<5

Comment: What @Sunny says is correct. You either need to change your condition to `j <= 4` or `j < 5`.

Comment: Yeah, I see it, and you are all right, just removed the extra "j" loop and modified both loops to i<=4 and now works perfectly, thank you all for your time. I´m learning more in a day here at stackoverflow that the last motnh at school :D

Comment: @Gabbo2483 - Yeah, remember that in a `for` loop, the loop continues until the condition is true. Which means, when you had `j <= 5`, then it continues through the loop an extra iteration then what was needed.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it should be `row[j]`

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
{
    Console.Write(row[j].ToString());
}
```

Comment: You are correct, should be "j" instead of "i". OMG!!! C´mon C#, it´s just a letter!!   :D     Thank you for your answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your view to this...

```
public void view()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The values are:");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write(row[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```